# Remove new line character in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use `getc(character)` to take an element from a file and do stuff with it, but it appears that it must have a `'\n'` before the end of a line is met.

How can I remove this so that when I copy the characters I don't have a new line character appearing anywhere - thus allowing me to deal with printing new lines when I choose?

Comment: no it isn't, i always say in my posts when i am doing homework

Comment: loz: Code Please!?! Not fair to be downvoting everyone's answer without us knowing.....

Comment: @tommieb75 : loz didn't downvote (he's still at 0 and learning how SO works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, wouldn't help to use getc to fill a buffer and remove newline and carriage return characters?

Comment: If he's using getc anyway, yeah it's probably smartest to just not copy the character into the buffer when doing that.

Answer (score 6):

```
.
.
.
#include <string.h>
.
. /* insert stuff here */
.
char* mystring = "THIS IS MY STRING\n"
char* deststring;
.
.
.
strncpy(deststring, mystring, strlen(mystring)-1);
.
.
.
```

(As an added note, I'm not a huge fan of dropping \0 characters in strings like that.  It doesn't work well when you start doing i18n and the character width is not fixed.  UTF-8, for example, can use anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes per "character".)

Answer (score 5):

To replace all new line char with spaces, use:

```
char *pch = strstr(myStr, "\n");
while(pch != NULL)
{
    strncpy(pch, " ", 1);
    pch = strstr(myStr, "\n");
}
```

To remove first occurrence of new line char in string, use:

```
char *pch = strstr(myStr, "\n");
if(pch != NULL)
  strncpy(pch, "\0", 1);
```

Comment: @Hector, now, I have added description.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace it with a null terminator.

Here is one (simple) way to do it off the top of my head:

```
 mystr[ strlen(mystr) - 1 ] = '\0';
```

Comment: shouldn't you verify that the char is a lf before nuking it?

Comment: Works fine until your employer decides to internationalize and your strings become UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Right, but your solution has the same problem. Typically you would need to use a different set of functions other than the str* series in order to deal with unicode. For example, using wcscpy instead of strcpy for Win32 programming. In any case, it was just a quick example.

Comment: @lexu - Do you mean the code should check to see that the char being replaced is a newline? Yes, that would probably be a good idea. However, all of the solutions more or less assume that his code is doing that check already.

Comment: That's what Kernighan & Pike suggested as idiomatic--in their The Practice of Programming p 26

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `buf` is of type `char` and it holds the string value read in from the file...

```
buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
```

That sets the second-last character of the buffer to nul i.e. '\0' in order to remove the new-line character.

**Edit:** Since loz mentioned a compiler error I suspect it's a `const char *` is used...Can we see the code please...

Comment: this gives an error saying passing arg 1 of strlen makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: shouldn't you verify that the char is a lf before nuking it?

Comment: Works fine until your employer decides to internationalize and your strings become UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Who downvoted this? We're shooting ourselves in the foot if loz did not post code...how are we supposed to know...

Answer (score 0):

**The following will do the trick**

```
line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complete version:

```
char* end = line + strlen(line) - 1 ;          // end of line                                                                                                      
while( (end > line) && isspace(*end) ) end--;  // right trim space                                                                                              
*(end+1) = '\0';                               // terminate string
```

(Note: Putting a null char into it makes string readers stop reading at that point but the memory footprint of line is the same. The characters to the right of the '\0' *are still there*.